# Which Django library to use for Facebook Graph API?

Tags: django, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm currently developing an application in Django and trying to implement Facebook authentication and requests to the Graph API.  I've seen a few different libraries out there, but what is the best way to do the following:

1. Have a user login via Facebook.
2. Django creates a new user for them and adds their uid and oauth token.
3. I can then make calls to the Graph API using Facebook's Python SDK.

I did see [this example](https://github.com/facebook/python-sdk/blob/master/examples/oauth/facebookoauth.py).  Is it that simple on normal Django?

Answer (score 2):

My company has built a library that makes integrating Facebook into your Django application dead simple (we've probably built 10-20 apps with the library, including some with huge amounts of traffic, so it's been battle-tested).

```
pip install ecl-facebook==1.2.7
```

In your settings, add values for your `FACEBOOK_KEY`, `FACEBOOK_SECRET`, `FACEBOOK_SCOPE`, `FACEBOOK_REDIRECT_URL`, and `PRIMARY_USER_MODEL`. You'll also need to add `ecl_facebook.backends.FacebookAuthBackend` to your `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`. For example, in *settings.py*:

```
# These aren't actual keys, you'll have to replace them with your own :)
FACEBOOK_KEY = "256064624431781"
FACEBOOK_SECRET = "4925935cb93e3446eff851ddaf5fad07"
FACEBOOK_REDIRECT_URL = "http://example.com/oauth/complete"
FACEBOOK_SCOPE = "email"

# The user model where the Facebook credentials will be stored
PRIMARY_USER_MODEL = "app.User"

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    # ...
    'ecl_facebook.backends.FacebookAuthBackend',
)
```

Add some views in your *views.py* to handle pre- and post-authentication logic.

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

from ecl_facebook.django_decorators import facebook_begin, facebook_callback
from ecl_facebook import Facebook

from .models import User

# ...

@facebook_begin
def oauth_facebook_begin(request):
    # Anything you want to do before sending the user off to Facebook
    # for authorization can be done here.
    pass

@facebook_callback
def oauth_facebook_complete(request, access_token, error):
    if error is None:
        facebook = Facebook(token)
        fbuser = facebook.me()
        user, _ = User.objects.get_or_create(facebook_id=fbuser.id, defaults={
            'access_token': access_token})
        user = authenticate(id=user.id)
        login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
    else:
        # Error is of type ecl_facebook.facebook.FacebookError. We pass
        # the error back to the callback so that you can handle it
        # however you want.
        pass
```

Now just hook up these URLs in your *urls.py* file and you're done.

```
# ...

urlpatterns = patterns('app.views',
    # ...
    url(r'^oauth/facebook/begin$', 'oauth_facebook_begin'),
    url(r'^oauth/facebook/complete$', 'oauth_facebook_complete'),
)
```

Hope this helps!

P.S. You can read the rest of the docs [here](http://packages.python.org/ecl_facebook/).

Answer (score 1):

We do a lot of Facebook Application development where I work, and so we've developed [an open-source library](https://github.com/jgorset/fandjango) that makes everything about it really easy.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from fandjango.decorators import facebook_authorization_required

@facebook_authorization_required
def foo(request, *args, **kwargs):
    return HttpResponse("Your name is %s" % request.facebook_user.first_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend https://github.com/egnity/fb.py. Got my Django-based Facebook app up and running in no time. It includes a middleware that allows you to run code like this in your view:

for the user id:

```
user_id = request.facebook.graph().get_object("me")['id']
```

for the oauth token:

```
user_token = request.facebook.auth_token
```

You can then add the above to your User model as you please. To make Graph API calls, you can still use fb.py's middleware -- no need for using the primitive python-sdk. The user_id code above is a perfect example of a Graph API call. There's much more you can do with fb.py. The download includes a sample django project to get you going.

Comment: That user/repo seems to have disappeared.

Comment: True. Try [https://github.com/emre/fb.py](https://github.com/emre/fb.py) - I think its the same project